# Android textview set max lines based on Stirng

Tags: android, gridview, textview

Hai I have few Textview with same width I am going to set text for each TextView These texts are a basically different length of texts. Now I want to set the maximum number of lines for all the Textviews based on the highest length of Textview.

Simply I want to find the maximum number of lines and set for all the TextView same maximum number of lines. Is there any possible way to o that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getLineCount()`

usage

```
public int getLine(Textview textview){
    textview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            return textview.getLineCount();
        }
    });
}
```

then you need to iterate all the textview

example: you have set of array of Textview

```
List<TextView> texts = new ArrayList<>();
texts.add(textview1);
texts.add(textview2);
texts.add(textview3);
```

then iterate all of them

```
List<int> number = new ArrayList<>();
for(TextView txt: texts){
    number.add(getLine(txt));
}
```

then compare the number

```
int maxNumber = Collections.max(number);
for(TextView txt: texts){
    txt.setMaxLines(maxNumber);
}
```

if you are using adapter in gridview...try this to get the view

```
public TextView GetViewByPosition(int position) {
    int firstPosition = this.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastPosition = this.getLastVisiblePosition();

    if ((position < firstPosition) || (position > lastPosition))
        return null;

    return (TextView)this.getChildAt(position - firstPosition);
}
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to implement it under Gridveiew getView method?

Comment: How to do that? Any clue?